# The parametrisation (cos(t),sin(t+a)) almost always seems to describe a rotated ellipse. How can I prove it?

Tags: trigonometry, elliptic-curves

I was wondering how a curve would look like if you have two hands of a clock moving at the same speed from different positions while you track the x of one hand and the y of the other hand over time. That's how I got (cos(t),sin(t+a)) where t is the time and a the angle between the hands.

It turned out to almost always describe an ellipse tilted by 45°. I have no idea why it is always tilted by that angle and how to show this parametrisation describes an ellipse.

My failed tries: 
1. Rotating (cos(t),sin(t+a)) by 45° and showing that the rotated points suffice the $\frac{x^2}{u^2}+\frac{y^2}{v^2}=1$ equation.

2. Using the distance to focal points definition for (cos(t),sin(t+a))

Maybe it's not possible to show in general because of the special cases where
(cos(t),sin(t+a)) describes a line. Please help!

I also failed showing it for a special a.

Sry for my bad english. I'm no native speaker

Comment: Setting $t=\pi/4$ doesn’t produce a vertex of any member of this family of ellipses, so if you tried to rotate it by offsetting $t$ by this amount, it’s not too surprising that you didn’t get anywhere with that.

Comment: Just for your future postings: this has nothing to do with elliptic curves, which typically are nonsingular plane *cubic* curves, while an ellipse is always a quadratic curve.

Comment: You can find Richard Borcherds ranting about how stupid the name "elliptic" is in a lecture of his.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate $t$ by expanding $y=\sin(t+a)$ into $y=\cos t\sin a+\cos a\sin t$ and then solve for $\sin t$ to get $(y-x\sin a)\sec a$, so that $$x^2+(y-x\sin a)^2\sec^2a=1,$$ which can be rearranged into the more standard-looking $$x^2-2xy\sin a+y^2=\cos^2a. \tag{*}$$ For $\cos a\ne0$, this equation indeed describes an ellipse. Using any of the usual methods, such as orthogonal diagonalization, its principal axes can be found to be in the directions $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$, i.e., its major axis is rotated 45° either clockwise or counterclockwise from standard position. When $\sin a=0$, you have a circle.

When $\cos a=0$, the implicit Cartesian equation (*) becomes $(x\pm y)^2=0$, i.e., a double line, but the original parametric equation only produces values of $x$ and $y$ in the interval $[-1,1]$, so the ellipse collapses to a line segment in this case.

Comment: Did you substitute cos t with x? That's something I didnt try before thanks. where does the sec^2 come from and how does it disappear one step later? Is it because I assume it to be a ellipse and then show it indeed suffices the equation?

How do I know that x^2+(y−x sin a)^2  sec^2 a equals 1?

Comment: 1 thing confuses me. You seem to multiply cos^2 a on both sides. Shouldnt it become cos^2 a x^2 then? Does it make it more compliacted? @amd

Comment: Ok I understood where the first equation came from. It s the trigonomentric pythagoras cos^2 + sin^2 = 1

Comment: @KimKaydo “Where does the $\sec^2t$ come from?” Solve for $\sin t$, as I’ve written. What’s its coefficient after expanding $\sin(t+a)$? “Shouldn’t it become $x^2\cos^2 a$?” Yes, but you also have an $x^2\sin^2a$ term to combine with it. Do the algebra. There’s nothing tricky involved. I’m not going to write out every little detail of those elementary manipulations.

Comment: @KimKaydo Yes, the key idea for eliminating $t$ from the parametric equations is to isolate $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ and then use that identity.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the equation $x^2 -2xy \sin a +y^2 = \cos^2 a$ 
we can assume a point (x,y) to have the coordinates (u,w) in a 45° rotated coordinate system.
(u,w) in the rotated system has the coordinates $(\frac{u-w}{\sqrt 2},\frac{u+w}{\sqrt 2})$ in the old system, so that $x=\frac{u-w}{\sqrt 2}$ and $x=\frac{u+w}{\sqrt 2}$.
Replacing x and y in the staring equation yields $u^2+w^2-\sin a (u^2-w^2)= \cos^2 a$
which can be simplified to

$$ \frac{u^2}{\cos^2 a \over 1-\sin a} + \frac{w^2}{\cos^2 a \over 1+\sin a} = 1$$ which is an ellipse for $\cos^2 a$ not equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
(\cos(t),\sin(t+a))=(\cos(t),\sin(t)\cos(a)+\cos(t)\sin(a))
$$
$$
\big\Updownarrow
$$
$$
(y-\sin(a)x)^2+\cos^2(a)x^2=\cos^2(a)
$$
$$
\big\Updownarrow
$$
$$
\begin{align}
2\cos^2(a)
&=2\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-\sin(a)\\
-\sin(a)&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\sin(a)&0\\
0&1+\sin(a)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
&=(1-\sin(a))(x+y)^2+(1+\sin(a))(x-y)^2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}{1+\sin(a)}+\frac{\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}{1-\sin(a)}=1
$$
which is an ellipse with semi-major and semi-minor axes of $\sqrt{1+\sin(a)}$ and $\sqrt{1-\sin(a)}$ rotated by $\frac\pi4$.